# Cesium issue positioning labels for GeoJSON markers

Tags: label, geojson, cesiumjs

I'm displaying some GeoJSON as markers in Cesium; they do not have altitude, so I'm using `clampToGround: true`. This all works.

When I try to label the markers, the labels only display when I'm zoomed far out. When I zoom in the labels disappear "underground", which is under the Terrain "layer".

How to solve this? I've looked at [this](https://community.cesium.com/t/points-labels-stuck-under-terrain/11141), but it didn't help in my case. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42328887/markers-in-cesium-are-cut) neither.

The code:

```
const viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer', {
  terrainProvider: Cesium.createWorldTerrain(),
  timeline: false, // Hide clock thing
  animation: false, // ditto
});    


// Add Cesium OSM Buildings, a global 3D buildings layer.
const buildingTileset = viewer.scene.primitives.add(Cesium.createOsmBuildings());   

// Fly the camera to the given longitude, latitude, and height.
viewer.camera.flyTo({
  destination : Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(11.952996, 57.671910, 400), 
  orientation : {
    heading : Cesium.Math.toRadians(0.0),
    pitch : Cesium.Math.toRadians(-15.0),
  }
});

var promise = Cesium.GeoJsonDataSource.load('data/botaniska_play.geojson', {
  clampToGround: true,
  markerColor: Cesium.Color.DARKGREEN,
});

promise.then (function (dataSource) {
  viewer.dataSources.add (dataSource);

  var entities = dataSource["_entityCollection"]["_entities"]["_array"];
  entities.forEach (entity => {
    // Add (and poistion?) label
    entity.label = new Cesium.LabelGraphics ({
      text: entity['_properties']['art']._value,
      //eyeOffset: new Cesium.Cartesian3 (0, 10, 0),
      horizontalOrigin: Cesium.HorizontalOrigin.LEFT,
      verticalOrigin: Cesium.VerticalOrigin.BOTTOM,
      pixelOffset: new Cesium.Cartesian2(0.0, -40.0), // Show above ground?
    });
  });
});
```

Snippet of the geojson:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[11.9531552705143,57.6814657645123]},"properties":{"ogc_fid":6,"geom":"{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[11.9531552705143,57.6814657645123]}","plats":"Test Plats","besikt_datum":"2013-06-07","trad_id":"6","art":"Magnolia stellata","status":null,"aldersfas":"Gammalt","hojd":9,"krondiameter":9,"stamdiameter":56,"skador":"Lindriga","vitalitet":"God","anmarkningar":"Vackert","rekommendationer":null,"risk":"Låg","resterande_risk":"-","atgards_datum":null,"atgard_gjort":null,"nasta_besiktning":"2014-06-07","stabiliserings_datum":null}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[11.9500765558289,57.6815427053798]},"properties":{"ogc_fid":21,"geom":"{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[11.9500765558289,57.6815427053798]}","plats":null,"besikt_datum":"2017-06-09","trad_id":null,"art":"Acer griseum","status":null,"aldersfas":"Vuxet","hojd":9,"krondiameter":8,"stamdiameter":50,"skador":null,"vitalitet":"God","anmarkningar":"Alléträd högt naturvärde\n","rekommendationer":null,"risk":"Låg","resterande_risk":null,"atgards_datum":null,"atgard_gjort":null,"nasta_besiktning":null,"stabiliserings_datum":null}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[11.9514171990732,57.6828566964894]},"properties":{"ogc_fid":3,"geom":"{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[11.9514171990732,57.6828566964894]}","plats":"Test Plats","besikt_datum":"2013-06-07","trad_id":"3","art":"Populus siemonii","status":null,"aldersfas":"Gammalt","hojd":15,"krondiameter":14,"stamdiameter":60,"skador":"Inga","vitalitet":"God","anmarkningar":"Fin","rekommendationer":null,"risk":"Låg","resterande_risk":"-","atgards_datum":null,"atgard_gjort":null,"nasta_besiktning":"2014-06-07","stabiliserings_datum":null}} ...
```

Comment: can you share your json?

Comment: Have added a snippet of the geojson to the question

Answer (score 1):

Try add `disableDepthTestDistance: Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY` to LabelGraphics options